# Does someone get a notice in case of a comment to a community wiki answer?

Tags: support, comments, community-wiki

I have posted a comment about an unused variable in code of an answer. The answer is marked as Community Wiki. Will the original author (who had ~79% of the edits) be informed about my comment?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, they will be notified.

I've always been notified when people comment on my CW posts (such as my [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts here on Meta) even though other people have edited the posts. (And yes, I was notified even before I became a moderator; that I now carry a diamond was not a factor).